# How to implement a login counter for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So in my ruby on rails project, I want to track how many times a user has logged in. I am using devise for authentication. Right now, I think what I have is sufficient for my current project, I am just having an issue incrementing the login_count column from my db.

Application.rb snippet:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.login_count == 0
      new_user_profile_path(user_id: current_user.id)
    else
      root_path
    end
    User.user_id.increment_counter(:login_count, 1)
  end
```

Right now `User.user_id.increment_counter(:login_count,1)` gives me `` undefined method `to_model' for 1:Integer Did you mean? to_yaml ``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’d be much better off providing a custom `SessionsController` and modifying the `create` action to perform the actions you require.

Use the devise generator to create controllers for you to work with, if you haven’t already. Then in your `sessions_controller.rb` add something like this:

```
def create
  super do |resource|
    # at this point, resource is your logged in user (or whatever model)
    resource.class.increment_counter(:login_count, resource.id)
  end
end
```